# What bonfire corresponds to the Darknight Stone-dropping Crystal Lizard?

Tags: dark-souls-2, dark-souls-2-sotfs

There is a [crystal lizard](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/crystal-lizard) on the wooden bridge on the way to the Gutter, which drops a [Darknight stone](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/darknight-stone).

Which bonfire do I need to use an [ascetic](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/bonfire-ascetic) on to resurrect that lizard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the posts [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/335300/discussions/0/517142892055222005/), the bonfire you need to use an ascetic on is the bonfire that resets the Royal Rat Vanguard.

> The bonfire to reset that lizard is the same one as the royal rat vangaurd, so you could kill the boss repeatedly and drop down to get the lizard on one asthetic each trip.

The bonfire you want to put an ascetic on, according to [this wikia page](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Royal_Rat_Vanguard), is Grave Entrance:

> By using a Bonfire Ascetic on the Grave of Saints bonfire, Grave Entrance, the Royal Rat Vanguard can be respawned.